# What are the differences between 'Other C Flags' and 'Preprocessor Macros' in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

It can be found in Build Settings.

For example, what are the differences below:

define -DDEBUG in Other c flags

and

define -DDEBUG in Preprocessor Marcos

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`preprocessor macros` build setting  is use to set initial value of preprocessor macros.

```
Example value: test_mode=1 copious_logging=1
```

`Other C Flags` build setting is use to send any arbitrary flag to the compiler.

```
Example value: -dM
```

Comment: But just like the default behavior in Xcode，it define -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 in Other C Flags
I am wondering that when I should user Preprocessor Macors or the other one

Comment: DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS suppresses the checks performed by NSAssert. its compile flag , so you should use Other C Flags. If you want conditional log, #ifdef DEBUG
#else
#endif, then you should use preprocessor macros